# RegExp return values between various square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:

[Value1][Value2][Value3][Value4][Value5]

And I need to get the value for each pair of square brackets. There can be 1 pair to a maximum of 5 pairs.

I've tried this:

```
var regExp = /\[(.*?)\]/
var matches = regExp.exec([A][B]");

console.log(matches[1]);
console.log(matches[2]);
```

I expect the console to output A and B, however for B I get undefined.

Comment: Please consider researching before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with [regex global flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global)

```js
var regExp = /\[(.*?)\]/g;
var matches = "[A][B]".match(regExp);

console.log(matches[0]);
console.log(matches[1]);
```

### Edit: for only getting contents in quare brackets:

```js
var regExp = /(?<=\[).*?(?=\])/g;
var matches = "[A][B]".match(regExp);

console.log(matches[0]);
console.log(matches[1]);
```

Comment: @xxxxxxxxxxxxx ... From how the OP was asking the Q. and presenting the problem I would assume that the expected result was rather `A` and `B` instead of `[A]` and `[B]`.

Comment: In order to retrieve the captured values in between the brackets one needs to change line 2 of your A. to `... matches = [..."[A][B]".matchAll(regExp)].map(([match, value]) => value);`

Comment: I've seen that while testing it but I just removed one char at the start and end of the resulting string. However your solution is more elegant. Thanks to both.